# How can I find if one or more array elements match in lodash find

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

Using `lodash` `_.find()`, we can see if there's a matching object in a collection.

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true,  arr: [2, 3, 6, 9] },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false, arr: [2, 3, 6, 9] },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true,  arr: [2, 3, 6, 9] }
];
```

You can provide an array, and an object matches if all values in that array are present in the collection. Notice the `arr`.

```
_.result(_.find(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true, 'arr': [2, 9] }), 'user');
// Result: "pebbles"
```

How can I match objects that have **one** (or more) matching **array items** for any array in the match object? (In this case `arr`.) Something similar to the `$in` query from `MongoDB`.

```
_.result(_.find(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true, 'arr': [2, 4] }), 'user');
// Result: undefined
// Expected: "pebbles"
```

Comment: find multiple times and add them to a set?

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](https://lodash.com/docs#find):

> If an object is provided for `predicate` the created `_.matches` style callback returns `true` for elements that have the properties of the given object, else `false`.

and [`_.matches`](https://lodash.com/docs#matches) does element-by-element equality tests with arrays so you can't use an object `predicate` for what you want to do. However, you don't have to pass an object to `_.find`, you can pass a function:

> Iterates over elements of `collection`, returning the first element `predicate` returns truthy for. The predicate is bound to `thisArg` and invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).

The object form of `_.find` that you're using just builds a predicate function behind the curtains. You can always supply your own predicate function if you need to:

```
_.find(users, function(value) {
    if(value.age !== 1)
        return false;
    if(!value.active)
        return false;
    if(_.intersection(value.arr, [2, 4]).length <= 0)
        return false;
    return true;
})
```

Of course, if your arrays aren't really sets (i.e. there could be duplicates or order matters) then you'd have to replace with `_.intersection` test with something that matches your specific requirements.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vo72Lyce/

If you want this to work for arbitrary objects then you'd write your own version of `_.matches` (probably by starting with the current implementation) that does what you want; then you could use your version of `_.matches` to build the predicate function for `_.find`.

Comment: Upvoted for now. This is _a_ solution. However, I have code-constructed objects that I want to pass to `_.find`. It would not be worth it to convert incoming objects to functions on the fly.

Comment: Then write your own version of `_.matches` as noted. When you pass an object to `_.find` it will convert that object to a function on the fly so that'll be happening no matter what.

Comment: Easier said than done. It's not about `_.matches`, it's about changing the `pridecate` function (which does some `getIteratee` magic) to change how it handles arrays. Everything is so interwoven, before you know it you are forking `lodash` and break everything just to change a behavior somewhere.

Comment: No it isn't. `_.matches` generates predicate functions that almost do what you want to do. `_.find` already takes a predicate function as an argument, it can also take an object (which it feeds to `_.matches`) but that's just for convenience. You can leave `_.find` alone so you don't need to care about the iteration side of things. The standard [implementation of `_.matches`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L2817) is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Yes it is easier said than done. Just take a look at the source code and `_.matches` itself is only a few lines. Nothing to edit there to change array behavior. It's hard to figure out how to do this. If it's easy, I suggest you edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot do that in lodash.

What `fuzzyMatcher` does is create an array of functions where each function corresponds to a single property in the object you are trying to match on. Those functions will return true if that property matches the property in the user object. Then `fuzzyMatcher` runs each of those functions and gets the count of the functions which returned true. Then it returns true if the number of matching functions is greater than or equal the number of desired matches (1 in your case).

This seems to work pretty well:

```
function fuzzyMatcher(collection, matchObj, minSimilarProps) {
    var matchFns = [];

    _.forOwn(matchObj, function(value, key) {
        matchFns.push(_.matchesProperty(key, value));
    });

    return _.find(collection, function(u) {
        return _.filter(matchFns, function(fn) {
            return fn(u);
        }).length >= minSimilarProps;
    });
}

//matches 1 properties
fuzzyMatcher(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true, 'arr': [2, 4] }, 1);

//or matches 2 properties
fuzzyMatcher(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true, 'arr': [2, 4] }, 2);
```

Or in your case:

```
_.result(fuzzyMatcher(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true, 'arr': [2, 4] }, 2), 'user');
```

Also I think you need to reword what you want to say "**two** or more" since once or more would match barney since active=1 in both cases.

Comment: Barney doesn't have `age=1`. And even if it did, then I would still want to be able to match that one as well. Thank you for the example. but I think you misunderstood the question. I only want to change the behavior of the matching of an array parameter, in this case `arr`. I want arrays to behave like _"If any of the elements appear in the collection document array, it's a match."_